# GeoWebCache does not display map

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, geowebcache

I'm using the GeoWebCache java app to display cached map images. I looked into the browser console and found in the response a 500 error, telling that there was a BeanInstantiationException due to a nested ClassCastException and the image does not displays. I went to the catalina.out logs of Tomcat and found the following:

```
20 sep 12:11:34 ERROR [servlet.DispatcherServlet] - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'gwcRuntimeStats' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/geowebcache-core-context.xml]: Instanti
ation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.geowebcache.stats.RuntimeStats]: Constructor threw exce
ption; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:254)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:925)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:835)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:440)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:221)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:429)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:729)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:381)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:402)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:316)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:282)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:126)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1088)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5176)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5460)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1113)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1671)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.geowebcache.stats.RuntimeStats]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:115)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:87)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:248)
        ... 35 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
        at org.geowebcache.stats.RuntimeStats.<init>(RuntimeStats.java:88)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:100)
        ... 37 more
```

This is the webpage where I'm using the GeoWebCache app http://ovie.mpiochih.gob.mx/#